# Vectors Velocity, Physics Word Problem.

Tags: vectors, mathematical-physics

> A bird is flying from Hamilton ON to Waterloo ON. There is a heavy
>   wind traveling at 5.0km/h (S11°E). What should its heading be? How
>   long will it take?

That is all the information I get and I am confused as to how to approach this problem because I don't have another velocity. I did some research and to get to Hamilton to Waterloo is 68km at a heading of (N60°W). I don't know if this information is relevant or even needed to answer the problem. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I guess it is assumed the bird will travel $5.0$ km/h faster with the wind in its back.

Comment: Yea, it would since the wind would be pushing it but it would also be changing the angle. I'm not sure how to calculate the angle for the heading since it's not a right angled triangle and I don't have another velocity so I can't use the cosine law either. ?

Comment: You need to know how fast the bird flies.

Comment: The first part is all the information we get. If I knew how fast the bird was flying I could answer this very easily.

Comment: It actually depends on the model you are using. Appart if you are studying the aerodynamic structure of birds I don't get how whoever made that exercise expect you to represent the action of wind on the bird (however, I don't think the speed of the bird would be relevant here.. But again it depends on the model you use I guess)

Comment: Haha no, I'm not studying anything about birds, it was just used as a moving object in this problem. We are supposed to add the vectors, wind + bird together to get a resultant. Can't really get a resultant with no velocity for the bird. I thought someone might know another way of solving this.

Comment: Well if this is about adding vectors, I guess indeed, some informations are missing somewhere.

Comment: Yea. One of my lessons said sometimes you can spilt up the vectors, so each has its own x and y components and makes a right angled triangle. Since you have a distance or velocity and an angle, you can then easily calculate the x and y for each vector then just add the x's and the y's for your new vectors and find the resultant that way. I tried it but one vector is for distance and the other for velocity and I have no way of converting either since I have to figure out the time as well. Very frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

There is always a useful right-angled triangle in a problem of this kind;
but it does not necessarily have any sides parallel to either of your
coordinate axes.

I prefer to represent the wind velocity as a vector pointing in the same direction that
the particles of air are moving. So if the direction the wind is coming from
is $11^\circ$ east of due south, the direction it is going to is 
$11^\circ$ west of due north.

The line the bird wants to travel (its *course*) is
$60^\circ$ west of due north. The angle between this and the wind direction
is $49^\circ$.
So the first right triangle to consider is one with an angle of
$49^\circ$ adjacent to the course from Hamilton to Waterloo
and a hypotenuse of $5$ km/h.

In order for the bird to fly in the directin of Waterloo in this wind,
its velocity vector plus the wind's velocity vector must be a vector
directly toward Waterloo.
SO draw a vector from the tip of the wind's vector back to the course
the bird wants to fly. Now you have a second right triangle with one leg
on the course, sharing its other leg with the other triangle.

Notice that the hypotenuse of the new triangle must be at least as
large as the shared leg.
If the bird flies slower than $5 \sin 49^\circ$ km/h, it will
not even be able to stay on course.

To fully solve the problem you need the bird's speed relative to the
surrounding air (its true airspeed).
Without this information, you can set up equations and find a formula
that gives the combined speeds of bird and wind along the course to
Waterloo, from which you can determine the time taken,
as well as the angles of the second triangle, from which you
can determine the bird's heading.
These formulas are the best answer you can give to a question with
this amount of information, I think.